# Unity C# error in variable decrementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a game in C# under Unity and I have a problem with the code for attack.

I've already tried to put this code in a void in the enemy script.

Enemy code :

```
public int Life = 5;
public int Speed = 100;
```

Player attack code :

```
    // Use for player attack
public void Attack () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
    EnemyD.Life = EnemyD.Life - 1;
    }
}

// Use for Auto Attack
public void AutoAttack () {
    EnemyD.Life = EnemyD.Life - 1;
}
```

Unity return this error :
error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Thank you for your help, Jason.

Comment: The code shown is not enough to understand what causes the problem. Please add more code, in particular the code of the Enemy class and the code around the decrement of the variable EnemyD

Comment: Enemy as no more code and for player is added right now.

Comment: Which line is the error on? If you double-click the error it should tell you.

Comment: Have you maybe got `==` (comparison) somewhere instead of `=` (assignment)?

Comment: The error indicates you are attempting an action on a type rather than an instance.

Comment: Error it's a this line : EnemyD.Life = EnemyD.Life - 1;

Comment: What is the definition of `EnemyD`?

Comment: EnemyD is : EnemyD = GameObject.Find("Enemy").GetComponent<Enemy>();

Comment: @JasonMadi so you are trying to reduce a life of a particular enemy when it gets hit, correct?

Comment: @NikolaG. , yes, it's exact.

Comment: There is still not enough information here, as the error you've provided would not normally occur with the code you've shown. Can you please post your **actual** code?

Comment: Here, all part of my code : http://www.mediafire.com/file/fzaen99s44uzpfp/code.zip/file

Comment: @JasonMadi you need to explain what you want, clearly the question is about the single enemy and not multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all enemies or group of enemies will have the same script, then you could call a particular script by grabbing whichever enemy was hit.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Monster"))
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyD>().Life -= 1;
    }
}
```

So if you have two enemies and you've attacked the first one, only on him will be applied this action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put scripts with proper `Class` name, I guess your enemy script is named `EnemyD`.

Let's come to point -  your player is trying to access member without an `instance`, so it is a error.

If you try to access them without `instance` you have to put `static` before members , which means **Of the class** , **Not of an instance**.

Normally there is so many enemy, we don't use static, instead use the approach of *Nikola G.* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669673/10305444)  [Posted as answer in this question].

Some links you might find helpful :

- [Static Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)
- [Class Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_variable)